# Package or namespace load failed

Tags: r

I'm getting this error while trying to install a package (via devtools/Github) (fastRPCA):

```
Package KlugerLab/rpca-mkl/fastRPCA is not yet installed
Install now?

1: yes
2: no

Selection: yes
Downloading GitHub repo KlugerLab/rpca-mkl@master
✓  checking for file ‘/tmp/RtmpLWpzW2/remotes39cf56b0e209e/KlugerLab-rpca-mkl-4eb4e22/fastRPCA/DESCRIPTION’ ...
─  preparing ‘fastRPCA’:
✓  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  cleaning src
─  installing the package to process help pages
         -----------------------------------
─  installing *source* package ‘fastRPCA’ ...
   ** using staged installation
   ** libs
   g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/home/tjcooper/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/Rcpp/include'    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-Do_dS_/r-base-4.0.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
   g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o fastRPCA.so RcppExports.o -L../inst/libs/ -Wl,-rpath,/tmp/RtmpVYp8ep/Rinst3bb172366e8f4/00LOCK-fastRPCA/00new/fastRPCA/libs -lfastpca -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
   installing via 'install.libs.R' to /tmp/RtmpVYp8ep/Rinst3bb172366e8f4/00LOCK-fastRPCA/00new/fastRPCA
   ** R
   ** inst
   ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
   ** help
   *** installing help indices
   ** building package indices
   ** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘fastRPCA’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
    unable to load shared object '/tmp/RtmpVYp8ep/Rinst3bb172366e8f4/00LOCK-fastRPCA/00new/fastRPCA/libs/fastRPCA.so':
     libfastpca_custommkl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
   Error: loading failed
   Execution halted
   ERROR: loading failed
─  removing ‘/tmp/RtmpVYp8ep/Rinst3bb172366e8f4/fastRPCA’
         -----------------------------------
   ERROR: package installation failed
Error: Failed to install 'fastRPCA' from GitHub:
  System command 'R' failed, exit status: 1, stdout + stderr (last 10 lines):
E> ** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
E> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘fastRPCA’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
E>  unable to load shared object '/tmp/RtmpVYp8ep/Rinst3bb172366e8f4/00LOCK-fastRPCA/00new/fastRPCA/libs/fastRPCA.so':
E>   libfastpca_custommkl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
E> Error: loading failed
E> Execution halted
E> ERROR: loading failed
E> * removing ‘/tmp/RtmpVYp8ep/Rinst3bb172366e8f4/fastRPCA’
E>       -----------------------------------
E> ERROR: package installation failed
```

I'm unable to pinpoint what the issue is by reading the output. Does anybody know how I can fix this?

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 | R: 4.0.0